# Probability of choosing n items from p, such that q of them are consecutive

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

I just noticed that I logged in to stackoverflow 816 days out of the last 1130, and still did not get the "Fanatic" badge (a badge you get for being active for 100 consecutive days). So, that made me wonder, what would be the probability of this happening? I tried solving it for a while but could not come up with any simple solution (other than doing a simulation. Code is my hammer :)).

Formally and generically I think the problem statement would be:
What is the probability of selecting "n" numbers from "p" consecutive numbers, such that no "q" of them are consecutive? (Please refine as needed)

I tried the grouping trick where you can consider the consecutive numbers are just one number, but that will end up repeat counting several groups. How to get around that?

Answer (score 0):

I think this post solves your issue: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27884/odds-of-x-occurrences-in-a-row-given-y-trials-a-coin-flip-problem

The first solution is limited to (total number of successes) < 2*(streak length), which isn't true for your question, but I think Neil G's answer (the second post) covers your problem. It's recursive rather than a pretty formula unfortunately.